# Which international tournament game has the record for the longest sequence of forced moves until checkmate?

Tags: checkmate, history, records, famous-games, forced-move

I want to know which international game has the longest sequence of forced moves until checkmate, even if the opponent resigned the game. The result should not be drawn, i.e. we should consider 50 move rule).

Comment: This is bound to be some boring endgame position that takes 50+ moves to checkmate against perfect defence...

Comment: @RemcoGerlich result should not be drawn.(i.e we should consider 50 move rule)

Comment: I know, but there could easily be a capture or pawn move in between.

Comment: With a forced move, do you mean the only winning move in a particular position ?

Answer (score 2):

Alekhine - Yates
http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1012179

19 moves.  Alekhine resigned a couple of moves before mate.